# Automatic name in dataset using paste

Tags: r, dataframe, paste

I'd like to put names in datasets automatically using `paste` or `paste0`. For example, if we consider a dataset with three variables, we have six columns and the expected result is

```
dta <- data.frame(matrix(1:60, ncol = 6))
names(dta) <- c('X1_dim1', 'X1_dim2', 'X2_dim1', 'X2_dim2', 'X3_dim1', 'X3_dim2')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `rep`

```
paste0("X", rep(1:ncol(dta), each = 2, length.out = ncol(dta)), "_dim", 1:2)
#[1] "X1_dim1" "X1_dim2" "X2_dim1" "X2_dim2" "X3_dim1" "X3_dim2"
```

`rep` generates sequence of length `ncol(dta)` with each element repeated twice

```
rep(1:ncol(dta), each = 2, length.out = ncol(dta))
#[1] 1 1 2 2 3 3
```